how to send keyboard strokes programmatically (like "sendkeys" in Windows) to a Wayland Linux window (KDE/GNOME)?
I'm writing a desktop automation software, which drives a GUI desktop, on linux. It works pretty well, but Wayland is blocking inter-window communication, especially when entering non-ASCII characters into text boxes.
For comparison, on Windows, I used sendkeys API, and most programs obeyed.
On X systems, there's pyautogui, xdotool, and other means, since there's no isolation between windows.
The programming solutions I've tested to drive and simulate user input:

uinput (python-uinput)
pyAutoGui -
ydotool ignores non-ASCII (officially). It runs its own daemon though, so it's slower than any direct API or DBus option.
wtype doesn't run on KDE nor Gnome.
dotool doesn't work for emoji, garbles nonascii
kdotool can't type characters.

There's a strict permissions issue with Wayland and how it (doesn't) permit(s) inter-window communication. But even when run as root, these tools don't allow non-ASCII characters.
I know some ugly workarounds, but they all come with a price tag, such as using the clipboard, and triggering a Ctrl+V event.
Any ideas how to send or emulate a keyboard event for unicode non-ASCII?
(I'm using Arch-derivatives with KDE, but the same is applicable to Gnome, and maybe other desktop environments.)

"but even with root, these tools don't allow non-ascii." You're mixing categories here! "ASCII" is an encoding for text, you are talking about keypress events – and of course, all these support representing the ü key being pressed in a German keyboard. It is just a keycode at that point, not a glyph representation for text storage; simply two different things :)

You can't "keypress" an emoji, because there's no keyboard layout with emojis on it. That makes perfect sense to me! It feels like you're trying to implement something specific, and (maybe incorrectly? Maybe correctly? Don't know!) assume that simulated keyboard strokes are the way to go. It does however, seem that you're not really interested in keyboard strokes, you want to insert emojis? It's not clear which "larger" problem you're trying to solve with this,  so it's impossible to help you with this. (We call this an X/Y-Problem.) Please tell us what you want to do, "in the larger picture"!

@MarcusMüller - Can you write a script / program / command line which sends an U+Umlaut to the active window? (in KDE+Wayland) ?  That's great!  please write it as an answer

no; you can only write scripts that send key presses. Whether that becomes an ü depends on the layout you've set. My ü keypress would become a ] on a US layout, for example.

again, feels unnecessary to ask again: Please edit your question to explain what you're trying to do "in the bigger picture".

hi marcus. The bigger picture is stated VERY CLEARLY in the first line of my question.

I did that already in X11 - sending characters which are not in any keyboard layout. And the universe didn't collapse.  If you don't know how to solve it, our relationship here has ended.

I explained that that's impossible, and it's not that I don't know how. I asked why you want to do that, because probably there are other ways to achieve what you wanted to achieve, without emulating key presses. But you don't have to help us help you! For these cases we have the "too broad" close reason, because if an answer would require us to cover all reasons we could think of you wanting to do something and then offering an alternative question with a solution for each of these reasons, it's simply too broad.

so you're pushing me to explain why I need to develop a desktop control app?  IDK, to earn money and fame?  i narrowed it down?

no, I'm explaining (not pushing, how would pushing work on a site where you're gifted free help? Are we maybe feeling a bit entitled today?) to you why we can't help you with the info you are giving. you don't have to help us help you. Have a great night!

For future reference, if you'd like a more supportive and positive response from the volunteer-based network it might help to not be snotty and condescending to the people who are sincerely interested in trying to help you figure out what exactly you're trying to do -- because clearly you don't quite understand it yourself.

solution:

installed keyd
set write permission to  /dev/uinput   (here's how)

in /etc/keyd/app.conf, add your key combo (for usage summary/tutorial go to man keyd or see keyd's github page)
For example:
to send any character to the active window, by pressing meta+o  (Winkey + letter o) :

in the /etc/keyd/app.info file, add section [meta] if not exist
write the key = character
this is how I did it:

[meta]
o = 

to get a list of possible key names, run keyd monitor in another terminal, and see the key names each key produces.

save the changes in the file
sudo keyd reload

now pressing Winkey+O gives  emoji, anywhere, on wayland !
I'm running kde on arch, of that matters.
p.s.
The unfortunate down side, is that I have now 2 separate places where key mapping is defined:   1) KDE shortcuts in the settings   2) /etc/keyd/app.info

maybe other solutions from the list of tools in my orioginal question - will work as well, after giving permission to /dev/uinput
